# Why isn't my php contact form sending?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I have a simple contact form appearing on a modal in bootstrap. For some reason my form will not send. I've been looking at it for the last few hours and could use a fresh pair of eyes. It seems so simple but I'm at a total loss.

I've put a non-displayed textfield in the form as a spam filter. Since most bots would fill the textfield I want the code to send only if the textfield is blank (which it should be if the user is human since it's not displayed).

**index.php**

```
<div class = "modal fade" id = "contact" role = "dialog">
  <div class = "modal-dialog">
    <div class = "modal-content">
      <div class = "modal-header">
        <a id = "btn-close" data-dismiss = "modal">X</a>  
      </div>
      <form>
        <form method="post" action="index.php">
          <fieldset id= "contact-fieldset">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="text-input" placeholder="First and last name" required>
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
            <input name="bot-catch" type="text" id="bot-catch">
            <input id="submit" class="submit-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </fieldset>
        </form>

<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $from = 'From: Me'; 
  $to = 'me@email.com'; 
  $subject = 'Hello';
  $human = $_POST['bot-catch'];    

  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

  if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
      echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
      echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
  } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
  }
?>

      </form>
      <div class = "modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  So I have now gotten my message to send, but only if I put the PHP code into a separate file and link to it by . Only problem is-  I do **not** want the user to be directed off of my page once they send a message. Is there anything I can do? I still can't figure out why it won't send on my index page.

EDIT: Well I got it working!! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Are you sure you have a mail server setup? Are you sure it isn;t being rejected by spam filters?

Comment: What output do you get ? Your message has been sent?

Comment: @JoniSalmi Unfortunately I'm not getting any feedback. Sorry I should have clarified. I press submit, the modal closes, and no message is sent.

Comment: @JohnConde A mail server? Sorry I'm new to this - just trying to set up my portfolio site. I checked my spam and junk email, but found nothing. From what I've read online I assume my server would be okay sending a message through my php script. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code for the modal dialog

Comment: @JoniSalmi  Sure thing. I've edited my original post to include the modal code.

Comment: You have two `<form>` tags. You do not need the first one. This may confuse older browsers. Remove the first one.

Comment: @JustinWood I wish that worked but the message still isn't sending. Thanks for the notice though. Does the code itself look okay? Should it work or have I missed something?